# Galaxy S9: Most apps keep stopping

Tags: crashes, samsung-galaxy-s-9

Galaxy S9: All day, most apps that I open will stop and immediately close. Apps running i the background repeatedly give the message "(app) keeps stopping".

I've removed the SD card, and started it in Safe Mode. I also wiped the cache partition and cleared the Chrome cache.

I'm using 57.1 GB out of 74, and memory shows 2.3 GB out of 4 used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall Android System Webview on the play store. I just did this and it fixed the issue.

Comment: That did it, thanks! I guess this was a known issue! In fact, Play Store says Webview was updated on my phone today -- and it had a lot of 1-star reviews yesterday!

Comment: +1, this did the trick on a Samsung Galaxy A5. How did you find out about this?